# syntax for HTTPRequest Syntax

Tags: javascript, http

When you load a page, your browser automatically sends an HTTP Request to get stylesheets and other resources.

Is there a manual way of getting stylesheets (not XMLHttpRequest). I am not making a form. I am just going to a page asynchronously, and the stylesheets will not load if i just change the `innerHTML`.

I am not using any third party libraries, so please don't give answers that depend on jQuery or the like.

Comment: I've tried to clean up your question to make it readable, but I don't understand what it is you are doing. What does "going to a page asynchronously" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This code loads the css/js file, by adding a **link** or **script** to dom, so I suppose it downloads the files as soon as the dom is changed with the new elements.

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml